# Elasticsearch client NEST not storing timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to create an Elasticsearch index and index a document using NEST.

I am querying the result through the Marvel Sense dashboard and can see that the index has been created and can see that my document has also been created, but there is no _timestamp field on the document.

When I try to view the index and documents through my Kibana dashboard it has a problem as it cannot find the timestamp to use with the filter.

I am created the index as follows:

```
var createIndexResult = _elasticClient.CreateIndex(errorIndex, c => c
                .NumberOfReplicas(0)
                .NumberOfShards(1)
                .Settings(s => s
                    .Add("merge.policy.merge_factor", "10")
                    .Add("search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "1s"))
                .AddMapping<ElmahErrorDocument>(m => m
                    .TimestampField(f => f
                        .Enabled()
                    )

                )
            );
```

And I am indexing my document as follows:

```
var indexResponse = _elasticClient.Index(errorDocument, i => i
                                .Timestamp(timestamp.ToString("o"))
                                .Type("elmah")
                                .Id(errorDocument.Id)
                            );
```

But for some reason I cannot see a _timestamp field when I query the result.

How do I get the timestamp to store when indexing documents using NEST?

Answer (score 1):

You can not get the _timestampfield in your query. Maybe you try this

```
elasticClient.CreateIndex("YourIndexName", c => c.AddMapping<yourClass>(m => m                    
                .MapFromAttributes()
                .TimestampField(t => t
                .Enabled(true)
                .Path(o => o.time)                                   
                )
             )
          );
```

It will use an attribute of your document ( in my cas `time` which is format as `DateTime`) for the `_timestamp` value.

You can check it by

```
 curl -X GET 'http://someip:9200/yourIndex/_mapping?pretty=true'
```

it should output something like this

```
{
"yourIndex" : {
"mappings" : {
  "index" : {
    "_timestamp" : {
      "enabled" : true,
      "path" : "time"
    },
    "properties" : {          
      "time" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
      },          
    }
  }
}
```

In Kibana you then have to use the `time` attribute for your Timestamp.